# my Struts 2 didn't work at all

Tags: eclipse, struts2, tomcat7

Helo All,
i'm very newb in Struts, in order to work as developer, i need to expert in Struts..
but, i should learn by my self and now, i got problem when i'm adding **struts.xml**

when i add **struts.xml** the result always shown **The requested resource is not available.**
when i remove it, it will come well wihtout Struts...

i've followed many simple tutorial using struts, but none of them worked on mine..

i think, there were no error in my console log...

```
Apr 10, 2013 10:17:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init INFO: The APR based
Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in
production environments was not found on the java.library.path:
C:\Program
Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program
Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files
(x86)\NVIDIA
Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth
Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI
Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files
(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft
Shared\Windows Live;. Apr 10, 2013 10:17:40 AM
org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin WARNING:
[SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting
property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:TryAgain' did not
find a matching property. Apr 10, 2013 10:17:40 AM
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] Apr 10, 2013 10:17:40 AM
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"] Apr 10, 2013 10:17:40 AM
org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load INFO: Initialization
processed in 893 ms Apr 10, 2013 10:17:40 AM
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFO: Starting
service Catalina Apr 10, 2013 10:17:40 AM
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal INFO: Starting
Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.39 Apr 10, 2013 10:17:41 AM
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info INFO: Parsing
configuration file [struts-default.xml] Apr 10, 2013 10:17:42 AM
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info INFO: Unable
to locate configuration files of the name struts-plugin.xml, skipping
Apr 10, 2013 10:17:42 AM
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info INFO: Parsing
configuration file [struts-plugin.xml] Apr 10, 2013 10:17:42 AM
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info INFO: Parsing
configuration file [struts.xml] Apr 10, 2013 10:17:42 AM
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info INFO: Choosing
bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory) Apr 10, 2013
10:17:42 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for
(com.opensymphony.xwork2.FileManagerFactory) Apr 10, 2013 10:17:42 AM
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info INFO: Choosing
bean (struts) for
(com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter) Apr 10, 2013
10:17:42 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for
(com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.CollectionConverter) Apr 10,
2013 10:17:42 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger
info INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for
(com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.ArrayConverter) Apr 10, 2013
10:17:42 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for
(com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.DateConverter) Apr 10, 2013
10:17:42 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for
(com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.NumberConverter) Apr 10, 2013
10:17:42 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for
(com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.StringConverter) Apr 10, 2013
10:17:42 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for
(com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ConversionPropertiesProcessor) Apr
10, 2013 10:17:42 AM
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info INFO: Choosing
bean (struts) for
(com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ConversionFileProcessor) Apr 10,
2013 10:17:42 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger
info INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for
(com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ConversionAnnotationProcessor) Apr
10, 2013 10:17:42 AM
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info INFO: Choosing
bean (struts) for
(com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.TypeConverterCreator) Apr 10, 2013
10:17:42 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for
(com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.TypeConverterHolder) Apr 10, 2013
10:17:42 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for
(com.opensymphony.xwork2.TextProvider) Apr 10, 2013 10:17:42 AM
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info INFO: Choosing
bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.LocaleProvider) Apr 10,
2013 10:17:42 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger
info INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for
(com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionProxyFactory) Apr 10, 2013 10:17:42 AM
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info INFO: Choosing
bean (struts) for
(com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ObjectTypeDeterminer) Apr 10, 2013
10:17:42 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for
(org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.mapper.ActionMapper) Apr 10, 2013
10:17:42 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (jakarta) for
(org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.MultiPartRequest) Apr 10,
2013 10:17:42 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger
info INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for
(org.apache.struts2.views.freemarker.FreemarkerManager) Apr 10, 2013
10:17:42 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for
(org.apache.struts2.components.UrlRenderer) Apr 10, 2013 10:17:42 AM
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info INFO: Choosing
bean (struts) for
(com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ActionValidatorManager) Apr 10,
2013 10:17:42 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger
info INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for
(com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ValueStackFactory) Apr 10, 2013 10:17:42
AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info INFO:
Choosing bean (struts) for
(com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.reflection.ReflectionProvider) Apr 10,
2013 10:17:42 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger
info INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for
(com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.reflection.ReflectionContextFactory) Apr
10, 2013 10:17:42 AM
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info INFO: Choosing
bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.PatternMatcher) Apr
10, 2013 10:17:42 AM
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info INFO: Choosing
bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StaticContentLoader)
Apr 10, 2013 10:17:42 AM
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info INFO: Choosing
bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.UnknownHandlerManager) Apr
10, 2013 10:17:42 AM
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info INFO: Choosing
bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.views.util.UrlHelper) Apr 10,
2013 10:17:42 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger
info INFO: Loading global messages from [ApplicationResources] Apr 10,
2013 10:17:42 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger
error SEVERE: Dispatcher initialization failed Unable to load
configuration. - action -
file:/C:/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/wtpwebapps/TryAgain/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:18:54
  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
  at
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:429)   at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:473)
  at
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
  at
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4746)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5399)
  at
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)  at
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)   at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)   at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)  at
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: Action class
[HelloWorld] not found - action -
file:/C:/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/wtpwebapps/TryAgain/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:18:54
  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.verifyAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:482)
  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:426)
  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:543)
  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:292)
  at
org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112)
  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:250)
  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
  ... 17 more

Apr 10, 2013 10:17:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
filterStart SEVERE: Exception starting filter Struts2Filter Unable to
load configuration. - action -
file:/C:/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/wtpwebapps/TryAgain/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:18:54
  at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:485)
  at
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
  at
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4746)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5399)
  at
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)  at
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)   at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)   at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)  at
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: Unable to load
configuration. - action -
file:/C:/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/wtpwebapps/TryAgain/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:18:54
  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
  at
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:429)   at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:473)
  ... 15 more Caused by: Action class [HelloWorld] not found - action -
file:/C:/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/wtpwebapps/TryAgain/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:18:54
  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.verifyAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:482)
  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:426)
  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:543)
  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:292)
  at
org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112)
  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:250)
  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
  ... 17 more

Apr 10, 2013 10:17:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
startInternal SEVERE: Error filterStart Apr 10, 2013 10:17:42 AM
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: Context
[/TryAgain] startup failed due to previous errors Apr 10, 2013
10:17:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR INFO:
Deploying web application archive
C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\webapps\FirstStruts-Try2.war Apr 10, 2013
10:17:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter   at
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)
  at
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:137)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4746)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5399)
  at
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
  at
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
  at
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown
Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown
Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)   at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)  at
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Apr 10, 2013 10:17:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
startInternal SEVERE: Error filterStart Apr 10, 2013 10:17:44 AM
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: Context
[/FirstStruts-Try2] startup failed due to previous errors Apr 10, 2013
10:17:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR INFO:
Deploying web application archive
C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\webapps\StrutsHelloWorld.war Apr 10, 2013
10:17:44 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger
error SEVERE: Dispatcher initialization failed
java.lang.RuntimeException:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:301)
  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:438)
  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$5.create(ContainerBuilder.java:207)
  at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)   at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$3.create(ContainerBuilder.java:93)
  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$7.call(ContainerBuilder.java:487)
  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$7.call(ContainerBuilder.java:484)
  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:584)
  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder.create(ContainerBuilder.java:484)
  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.createBootstrapContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:323)
  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:221)
  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
  at
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:429)   at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:473)
  at
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:193)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4746)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5399)
  at
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
  at
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
  at
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown
Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown
Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)   at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)  at
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:299)
  ... 31 more Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStackFactory.setContainer(OgnlValueStackFactory.java:84)
  ... 36 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Javassist
library is missing in classpath! Please add missed dependency!  at
ognl.OgnlRuntime.<clinit>(OgnlRuntime.java:168)   ... 37 more Caused
by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.ClassPool   at
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)
  at
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  at
java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)   at
ognl.OgnlRuntime.<clinit>(OgnlRuntime.java:165)   ... 37 more

Apr 10, 2013 10:17:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
filterStart SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException - Class:
com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector File:
ContainerImpl.java Method: inject Line: 301 -
com/opensymphony/xwork2/inject/ContainerImpl.java:301:-1  at
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:485)  at
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:193)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4746)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5399)
  at
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
  at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
  at
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
  at
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown
Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown
Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)   at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)  at
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
java.lang.RuntimeException:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:301)
  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:438)
  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$5.create(ContainerBuilder.java:207)
  at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)   at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$3.create(ContainerBuilder.java:93)
  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$7.call(ContainerBuilder.java:487)
  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$7.call(ContainerBuilder.java:484)
  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:584)
  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder.create(ContainerBuilder.java:484)
  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.createBootstrapContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:323)
  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:221)
  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
  at
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:429)   at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:473)
  ... 18 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:299)
  ... 31 more Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError  at
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStackFactory.setContainer(OgnlValueStackFactory.java:84)
  ... 36 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Javassist
library is missing in classpath! Please add missed dependency!  at
ognl.OgnlRuntime.<clinit>(OgnlRuntime.java:168)   ... 37 more Caused
by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.ClassPool   at
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)
  at
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  at
java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)   at
ognl.OgnlRuntime.<clinit>(OgnlRuntime.java:165)   ... 37 more

Apr 10, 2013 10:17:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
startInternal SEVERE: Error filterStart Apr 10, 2013 10:17:44 AM
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: Context
[/StrutsHelloWorld] startup failed due to previous errors Apr 10, 2013
10:17:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory
C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\webapps\docs Apr 10, 2013 10:17:44 AM
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO: Deploying
web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\webapps\examples Apr
10, 2013 10:17:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized() Apr 10, 2013 10:17:45 AM
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: SessionListener:
contextInitialized() Apr 10, 2013 10:17:45 AM
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: ContextListener:
attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache',
'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@634fbcac') Apr 10, 2013
10:17:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory
C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\webapps\host-manager Apr 10, 2013 10:17:45 AM
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO: Deploying
web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\webapps\manager Apr
10, 2013 10:17:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig
deployDirectory INFO: Deploying web application directory
C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\webapps\ROOT Apr 10, 2013 10:17:45 AM
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] Apr 10, 2013 10:17:45 AM
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"] Apr 10, 2013 10:17:45 AM
org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start INFO: Server startup in
4929 ms
```

i used these lib as the tutorial gives

```
asm-3.3.jar      
asm-commons-3.3.jar      
asm-tree-3.3.jar      
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar      
commons-io-2.0.1.jar      
commons-lang3-3.1.jar      
freemarker-2.3.19.jar      
javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar      
log4j-1.2.9.jar      
ognl-3.0.6.jar      
struts2-core-2.3.12.jar      
xwork-core-2.3.12.jar
```

Comment: I don't think you reading the struts.xml from right folder path ... in the error information you posted, eclipse is looking at ../C:/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/wtpwebapps/TryAgain/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml.. did you store the xml file in this location?

Comment: I think you should get someone who understand maven with your IDE of choice to sit down with you and go though the getting started section found on the struts2 web site.

Comment: I think you have to add struts.xml to the classpath.

Comment: Some knowledge of Eclipse IDE to develop dynamic web applications is required. Especially how it's managing dependencies at deployment.

Comment: OK, i got it...i think i should learn more, because i really didn't know about those error log,,, after i make new project it goes well, maybe i just to rush with trying many thing in my project before..thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How can you possibly think there are no errors in your log?

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter   at
```

Which is true, there is no such class. The filter is:

```
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
```

It looks as though you also have a number of class/library issues, possibly caused by version conflicts.

Comment: yep...i think thats the problem...i'm trying to combine from many tutorial and get confused witch one is correct... and i just realize that i read in many different version from struts 1 and struts 2...Thank you..